KendoUI jQuery grid column template with `values` field not works
I have defined following jQuery datagrid column. Users is assoc array of text and value fields. Column is correctly displaying users's fullname from values field.
(new Kendo\UI\GridColumn())
                ->field('modified_by')
                ->title($t->translate('card.grid.modified_by'))
                ->values($users)
                ->filterable($filterableMulti)
                ->width(200)
                ->lockable(true)

Now I need to change the column value into the link and therefore, I added template field to custom render column value.
Problem is, that I don't know and I didn't find it also in documentation, how to parse "modified_by" value into the user fullname (with using of text-value array in values field).
(new Kendo\UI\GridColumn())
                ->field('modified_by')
                ->title($t->translate('card.grid.modified_by'))
                ->values($users)
                ->filterable($filterableMulti)
                ->width(200)
                ->template('#= (modified_by == null) ? \'\' : \'<a href="' . $this->baseURL . 'profile/\'+modified_by+\'">\'+modified_by+\'</a>\' #')
                ->lockable(true)

